# React router not rendering the correct component

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am having a weird problem with react routing and this might just be something stupid. I a route `/products` which renders a component. Now I am trying to make another route `/products/:id/confirmation-email` but react redirects me to the products component. If I change either of the routes to something else it works fine.

```
<ProtectedRoute
        path="/products"
        component={Products}
/>

<ProtectedRoute
        path="/products/:id/confirmation-email"
        component={ConfirmationEmail}

/>
```

Comment: can you add code to the question ?

Comment: @adityakumar look at it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the confirmation route above the products route in your code like this.

```
<ProtectedRoute
        path="/products/:id/confirmation-email"
        bootIntercom={bootIntercom}
        trackPageVisitOnMixpanel={trackPageVisitOnMixpanel}
        component={ConfirmationEmail}

/>

<ProtectedRoute
        path="/products"
        bootIntercom={bootIntercom}
        trackPageVisitOnMixpanel={trackPageVisitOnMixpanel}
        component={Products}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `exact` props inside your route.

```
  <ProtectedRoute
            exact 
            path="/products"
            bootIntercom={bootIntercom}
            trackPageVisitOnMixpanel={trackPageVisitOnMixpanel}
            component={Products}
    />

<ProtectedRoute
        exact  
        path="/products/:id/confirmation-email"
        bootIntercom={bootIntercom}
        trackPageVisitOnMixpanel={trackPageVisitOnMixpanel}
        component={ConfirmationEmail}
```